# How to return no result?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have following data set

```
1   CCID        CEID    COM_ID  OSN_zasl_5_special
2   195540560   3863357 28810   INFO_support
3   197562575   3863357 8307    LIST_zav_splatky
4   197307065   3863357 29760   OSN_dat_prvej_spl
5   197307066   3863357 8508    CS_sprava_kod 6
6   198284541   3863357 8508    CS_sprava_kod 6
7   198297147   3863357 29030   CS_sprava_kod 54
8   199288740   3863357 2121    PA02
```

This is what i need, if "ceid" has comment with id 8307 (com_id) return no result. In other words i have this query

```
select table.ceid from table
where table.com_id != 8307
```

But this query will return this ceid, because there exists multiple entries with same ceid which doesn't contain this comment id.

I have tried to group by ceid use stragg on com_id and then stragg(com_id) not like 'com_id' but that doesnt seem to do the trick. Is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.ceid = t.ceid and t2.com_id = 8307);
```

Sometimes, it can be useful to do this using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when com_id = 8307 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by ceid) as cnt_8307
      from t
     ) t
where cnt_8307 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
select table.ceid from table
minus
select table.ceid from table
where table.com_id = 8307
```

Comment: That would produce the same result as the OP's query.

Comment: @1010 Well, it doesn't. First quey might have multiple CEIDs, like `3863357 `, the second query would have only one `3863357`, but it's enough to get rid out of these in first query. Refer to this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1649/8